# Jenkins Plugins install issue with SCM API and Jenkins Version

Tags: plugins, jenkins

am getting error,when I try to install the jenkins plugins like scm api, github, git etc.

```
`java.io.IOException: SCM API Plugin v2.5.1 failed to load. - You must update Jenkins from v2.156 to v2.164.3 or later to run this plugin.

 at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolve PluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:797)
at hudson.PluginManager.dynamicLoad(PluginManager.java:905)

 Caused: java.io.IOException: Failed to install scm-api plugin
at hudson.PluginManager.dynamicLoad(PluginManager.java:915)
at hudson.PluginManager.dynamicLoad(PluginManager.java:851)
at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:2037)
```

also, when i tried to install Git plugin, i got another error:

```
 `java.io.IOException: Jenkins Git plugin v3.10.0 failed to load.
 - scm-api v2.2.6 is missing. To fix, install v2.2.6 or later.
 - git-client v2.7.7 is missing. To fix, install v2.7.7 or later.
 - mailer v1.18 is missing. To fix, install v1.18 or later.
 - workflow-scm-step v2.4 is missing. To fix, install v2.4 or later.
 - matrix-project v1.7.1 is missing. To fix, install v1.7.1 or later.
    at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies
```

what am doing wrong